# how to make folders and return delete this folders use with batch codes?

Tags: batch-file

I want to do make folders and delete the folders.

```
:a
mkdir %random%
goto b
goto a

:b
rd /s /q %random%
```

is not work for make folders and re delete the folders. How to do?

Make many folders and 30 seconds later this folders are delete.

Comment: I don't know about the create and delete commands, but what you have here is an infinite loop; I cannot imagine any scenario where this is a good thing. Why are you trying to do this? Let us know and we might have a better solution.

Comment: this is not infinite, it executes once, than the goto b goes to b, and the rd executes, than the code stops.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a guide on how it can be done.

```
:a
set "folder=%random%"
if not exist "%folder%\" mkdir "%folder%"
pause
goto b

:b
rd /s /q "%folder%"
goto a
```

Comment: I'm confused on the use of the :b label and go to b commands. are they just there for similarity to the OP's code, or did i miss something?

Comment: @nephi12 Yes, just to make it similar in format - they are not needed, as you are aware.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
:a
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do md "air plot%%i"
timeout /nobreak 30 >nul 2>nul
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do rd /s /q "air plot%%i"
goto a
```

Comment: Please don't beg for reputation, especially immediately after answering the question and before the poster can even see it.

Comment: Sorry, but you posted the answer, and less than 1 minute later posted a comment asking for it to be accepted if it helps. It's unnecessary noise and clutter that isn't needed (or wanted) here. Comments are for asking for more information or suggesting improvements, as are clearly indicated when you click "Add comment" in the text area for entering the comment.) If your answer deserves upvotes, it will get upvoted. Please refrain from posting comments that ask for acceptance or upvotes, especially seconds after posting the answer itself.

Comment: Also, you might learn to accept constructive criticism from people who have more experience here than you. :-)

Comment: If take down :a and goto a. It more good.IF include :a and goto a command are create but not re del the folders. I am a young study,i think this bat command is benefit for me by helped. a Y S.

Comment: how to make air plot.folder(air space plot) in this process. I try with do md "" "air plot"%%i and do rd /s /q "" "air plot"%%i. It come by sth in create folders. But re del folders are not get.

Comment: @KenWhite as i stated, i was not looking for rep. i am frigging thirteen, and rep here does me no good. i was trying to follow advice givin to me by another member here, one who at the time was one of the top. he told me to except an answer, that excepting ansers is a way to help people learn and find answers quickely. also, i have been doing this for quite some time, and not only are you the only one to repond in such a manner, but many people have upvoted those comments. also, i never once asked for an upvote

Comment: The `accept` feature is largely ignored by a great many new posters.  I don't expect my reputation figure to reflect my usefulness to the community, and I just add my input when I think I can help.  Ken has posted almost as many down votes as he has upvoted, which shows his nature.

Comment: @foxidrive you were the person who told me! i had a different user name(back when i used Facebook instead of Google, and never merged) and you were the one who told me to. thank you for it, and for continuing to help the community grow and learn. you are the user i look up to always, and i never cease to learn from your posts and comments.

Comment: Thanks nephi12.  I do still post a reminder sometimes about accepting answers, I did it yesterday on another persons answer.  Keep in there...  I also enjoy this forum.

Comment: just a quick note to the down-voter: if you down-voted because my answer was bad, thank you, that is what they are for. if you down-voted because the comments were bad, that should have been dealt with with flags, so the comment gets dealt with if necessary.